# If $a,b,c>0 $ then $\frac{9}{a+b+c} \leq 2\left( \frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c} \right)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Let $a,b,c>0$ then show taht $\frac{9}{a+b+c} \leq 2\left( \frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c}\ \right)\leq \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$.

For show the RHS I do the following.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}{2} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}\geq \frac{1}{\frac{a+b}{2}}=\frac{2}{a+b}
\end{equation}
Now notice that we can do the same for the other terms, now we have the following.
\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}}{2} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}\geq \frac{1}{\frac{b+c}{2}}=\frac{2}{b+c}
\end{equation}
And

\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}}{2} \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{ac}} \geq \frac{1}{\frac{a+c}{2}}=\frac{2}{a+c}
\end{equation}
and sume the LHS and RHS of those inequalitys we get

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \geq 2\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c} \right) 
\end{equation}
Therefore we have the RHS of the inequality Holds.
Now for the LHS I don´t know how I should apply the inequialitys, I tryed a lot of things for get a lower bound of $a+b+c$ and get a upper  bound of $\frac{1}{a+b+c}$ but I don´t get it.

I try look the expression like $$\frac{3}{\frac{a+b+c}{3}}$$ and apply the GM-AM inequality but it doesn´t work.Still I try use the fact that
$$a+b+c\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{bc}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{ac}} \geq \frac{2ab}{a+b}+\frac{2bc}{b+c}+\frac{2ac}{a+c} $$
And take inverses, but I don´t get the LHS.

Any advice or hint of where I should apply the GM-AM inequality or how Prove the LHS was very useful.

Comment: Hint: Try applying the Cauchy Schwarz inequality.

Comment: In the book the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality comes the next pages, there exists other form without apply Cauchy Schwarz inequality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove $\frac{9}{a+b+c} \leq 2\left( \frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c} \right)$, we can observe that
$$a+b+c = \frac 12((a+b)+(a+c)+(b+c))$$
denote $x = (a+b),y = (b+c),z=(a+c)$ and we get what we want to prove after simplify
$$\frac {9}{\frac 12 (x+y+z)} \le 2(\frac 1x + \frac 1y +\frac 1z)$$
Use Cauchy Schwarz Inequality directly as follows
$$
(\frac 1x + \frac 1y +\frac 1z)(x+y+z) \ge (1+1+1)^2 =9 
$$

**Or**

we can use the **GM-AM inequality only**$ \frac {\frac 1x + \frac 1y +\frac 1z}{3} \ge (\frac {1}{xyz})^{\frac 13}$ and $\frac {x+y+z}{3} \ge (xyz)^{\frac 13}$
,we can again get the above result.

**Or**

we can use the GM-AM inequality $\frac {\frac 1x + \frac 1y +\frac 1z}{3} \ge (\frac {1}{xyz})^{\frac 13}$, then ,
just to prove
$$
\frac {3}{x+y+z} \le (\frac {1}{xyz})^{\frac 13}
$$
which can be simplified as follow
$$
(x+y+z)^3 \ge 27xyz
$$
This has been prooved in [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48621/inequality-x-y-z3-geq-27-xyz)

**I am very grateful to River Li. He helped me a lot here**

Comment: Thanks for voting my answer. By the way, if you like my answer please accept it as the answer to your question. I will be very gratefull

Comment: Please check the 2nd line: do you mean $\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c} = \frac {2(a + b+ c)}{(a + b)(a+c)(b+c)}$?

Comment: Should it be $\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c} = \frac{(b+c)(a+c) + (a+b)(a+c) + (a+b)(b+c)}{(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)}$?

Comment: @River Li , oh, my mistake, I am patching this vulnerability ，thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Hope you can revise it.

Comment: You last inequality is not true. It should be $(x+y+z)^2 - 3(xy + yz + zx) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - xy -y z - zx \ge 0$. You may try: $x + y + z \ge 3(xyz)^{1/3}$ and $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} \ge 3(\frac{1}{xyz})^{1/3}$, then ...

Comment: Yeah , I am try it , thanks

Comment: Now , please check my answer again , is there any question? Or you have a better method to improve it. @River Li

Comment: It is fine. Alternatively, by AM-GM, we have $x + y + z \ge 3(xyz)^{1/3}$ and $\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} \ge 3(\frac{1}{xyz})^{1/3}$. Thus, we have $(x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}) \ge 9$. We are done.

Comment: That's great !!! That's the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality. Thank you very much.

Comment: Multiplying them to get $(x+y+z)(\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z}) \ge 9$. We do not use Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz. We only use AM-GM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121270/discussion-between-hugo-and-river-li).

Comment: Your solution is fine.

Comment: Awesome! solution you get my +1

Answer (score 1):

Just another way, if you're familiar with [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality), the  inequality in question is just the majorization $(a, b, c) \succ \left(\frac{a+b}2,\frac{b+c}2, \frac{c+a}2 \right) \succ \left(\frac{a+b+c}3,\frac{a+b+c}3, \frac{a+b+c}3 \right)$ applied to the convex function $t \mapsto \frac1t$.

Comment: or to put it simple its just the AM-HM inequality :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a variant of Cauchy-Schwarz which goes like this: consider $a_1,...,a_n \in \Bbb{R}$ and $b_1,...,b_n>0$. Then
$$ \frac{a_1^2}{b_1}+...+\frac{a_n^2}{b_n} \geq \frac{(a_1+...+a_n)^2}{b_1+...+b_n}.$$
To prove this, just multiply with $b_1,...,b_n$ and observe that the inequality coincides with Cauchy-Schwarz for $(a_i/\sqrt{b_i})$ and $(\sqrt{b_i})$.

Applying this inequality directly gives the result you want.

$$ \frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a} \geq \frac{9}{2(a+b+c)}$$